# function for change Date Format in android

Tags: android

I have input date in following format (mm - dd - yyyy) and i want to send it on server (yyyy -mm -dd) from android .

write a function to convert input date to output date.

Comment: "write a function to convert input date to output date." you can't ask here like this

Comment: Try your hand with `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SimpleDateForat

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
          Date dateObj = null;
        try 
        {
            dateObj = curFormater.parse(oldDateStr);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
          SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

         String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
```

Comment: i have tried SimpleDateFormator but output is garbage. my input is 30-4-2012 then its return output 2012- 1- 30. its shows first month in case of every months

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote a class to return date with new format,

### 2013-03-27 13:48:50 To Mar 27, 1PM

> Initially i too received wrong value JAN instead of MARCH, I realized the result bc I did used
>
> ### mmm dd, hha  instead of MMM dd, hha

```
public class DateFormatConvertor {

public String changeDateFormat(String dateString) {

    SimpleDateFormat recivedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, hha",
            Locale.US);
    Date dateObj = null;
    try {
        dateObj = recivedFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "-";
    }
    return outputFormat.format(dateObj);
}
```

}